# What is the css computation source of an element on google page

Tags: javascript, css, dom, browser, styling

Was inspecting https://www.google.com and have no ideas where the styling is coming from. Maybe someone have ideas how to locate it and how is it hidden from me.
 1. Screenshot(node): https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcYuN.jpg (any "a" tag in popup, e.g. Search/Maps/Play)
 2. Linked style(node): https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo2PC.jpg
P.S. this styles(`transform`) got "from nowhere"(at least for me) only at non-anonymous mode, in anonymous everything works as expected.
UPD: styles differs when i'm logged in/not logged it.
looks like style node isn't recalculated after change(? see comments below)
 Therefore question is: why is it not recalculated/how to repeat such behavior?
*looks like not everyone can reproduce behavior on that site

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187077/discussion-on-question-by-yaroslav-stasyuk-what-is-the-css-computation-source-of).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like change is happening from script that came from https://www.gstatic.com (don't think it can be extension).
No information about this stylings(inline or in `<style>` tag content) because it's changed via `document.cssStylesheets[].insertRule()`

Same affect(no changes in `<style>` content) can be achieved via modifing rule directly, e.g. `document.styleSheets[].cssRules[].style.transform = "${value}"`